# Laravel url() and secure_url() method with custom ports

Tags: url, ssl, laravel, laravel-4

We have custom ports depending on the environment of the installation. Furthermore we sometimes check to require HTTP, HTTPS or don't care about the HTTP status.

For this purpose I sometimes need to redirect to HTTP or HTTPS - with a custom port. However, the `url()` and `secure_url()` functions in Laravel do not provide the desired functionality as far as I can see.

> Example HTTP port: 8070
>   Example HTTPS port: 8071
>
> Request to: https://project.local:8071/sweden

This request I want to redirect to `HTTP`.

```
url( secure_url(Request::getRequestUri() );
```

returns 
`http://project.local:8071/sweden` (wrong port, taken from current request)

Same same goes the other way around, if the request was via HTTP on port `8070`, then the `secure_url()` method returns a URL with the HTTP port `8070` instead of `8071`.

**Question**: How can I configure the ports used for the `url()` and `secure_url()` functions?

(either as a global configuration, or by adding a parameter to the function calls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laravel URL generation code does not take ports into account.

Comment: Yeah, appears so. We've worked around this by creating a wrapper for the URL builder with more options, and also taking a custom port config file into account, which we created.